# Get page access token by app access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, token, facebook-page

I could not get my user page access token. I have enabled manage_pages in permission of my application settings.

When i access the Graph API I got blank data, no access token.

```
  /page_id?fields=access_token
```

I am having the understanding that we can get user page access token by configuring manage_page permissions.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#page_access_tokens

Comment: Have you tried `/USER_ID/accounts` endpoint to retrieve access token?

Comment: Yes. I got blank data.

Comment: I have tried from my Graph API explorer /USER_ID/accounts. I got blank data

Comment: Oh, sorry it should be `me/accounts`. Try this in Graph API explorer and you would see you page in with name and access token along with other information.

Comment: Can you double confirm the access token have manage_pages scopes(permission) on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug?